# Gridview always show previous selected row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, user-controls, posting

I am updating gridview after selecting row and then clicking edit which works perfectly but one thing is annoying me that whenever i visit that gridview that it shows that ROW SELECTED and Colored. Why ? i want fresh gridview with no record of previous selected data.

CODE:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session.Count <= 0)
        {
            Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
        }

        lblMsgPopUp.Visible = false;
    }

protected void btnUpdatePopUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        try
        {
            int ComplainantTypeID = Convert.ToInt32(txtSelectedID.Text.Trim());
            ComplainantTypeBizz comBizz = new ComplainantTypeBizz(txtName.Text);
            ManageComplainantType mngComplainantType = new ManageComplainantType();

            bool Result = mngComplainantType.Update(comBizz, ComplainantTypeID);

            if (Result == true)
            {
                HiddenFieldSetMessage.Value = "Updated";
                HiddenFieldShowMessage.Value = "True";
                Clear(txtName);
            }
            else
            {
                HiddenFieldSetMessage.Value = "NotUpdated";
                HiddenFieldShowMessage.Value = "True";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            HiddenFieldSetMessage.Value = "NotUpdated";
            HiddenFieldShowMessage.Value = "True";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Bind the Gridview after updation

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind the data to the gridview (`GridView.DataBind();`) after you edit it in the `RowUpdated` event and set the `GridView.SelectedIndex = -1;` after each data bind to unselect any row in your grid.

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdated(object sender, GridViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.DataBind();
    GridView1.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: ok but i can't figure out that where to put your code exactly ? please help me in code